# Site can't be reached after logging in through Selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to scrape log-in based website using selenium-python. When I click on login button, it shows me something like below in the image.

[image]

This is What I've tried so far:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

url = 'https://www.company.ai/account/login'

driver.get(url)
# driver.implicitly_wait(10)

time.sleep(5)
username = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='username']")))
username.send_keys("EMAIL_ADDRESS")

password = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[placeholder='Password']")))
password.send_keys("PASSWORD")

time.sleep(5)

button = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[type='submit']")))

# driver.implicitly_wait(5)
button.click()

time.sleep(10)

# Extract data from the dynamically loaded content
newURL = 'url1.com'
data = driver.get(newURL)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
print(data.title)

# driver.quit()
```

Any idea how to bypass this page?

Comment: The url you provide has no ssl certificate. It seems that domain need to be purchased. And there is no email and password field for login. So it is not possible to do automation with the link.

Comment: I did that way just for security purpose, the code has everything it needs like proper HTTPs url, username and password. Do you have any workaround for this?

Comment: Yes I have, I can help you if u provide me proper url and creds to login .